# Paragraph element that doesnt have two line breaks

Tags: html, css, element, line-breaks

I have a div with two paragraph elements inside like so:

```
<div id="statsDiv"">
  <p id="scoreCounter">Score: </p>
  <p id="timeCounter">Time: </p>
</div>
```

It shows this:

Score:

Time:

I don't want a gap between the two elements, such that it gets shown like so:

Score:
Time:

The above was done with the following HTML:

```
Score:<br>
Time:
```

I also don't want the two elements to be one, since I am making a web game ando nly want to have to modify one of the two, not have to update both each time.

I also want to stick an options button inside of the same div.

Is there some CSS I could use to remove the line break between the two? Or else some different element that I could use to have the text able to be selected by their ID and have the inside text changed?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Try `.statsDiv { display: inline; }`?

Comment: remove the default margin between p

Answer (score 0):

---

```html
 <div id="statsDiv"">
  <p id="scoreCounter">Score: <br><span>Time:</span></p>

</div>
```

**strong text**